# Angular: Get parent and specific child from JSON

Tags: arrays, json, angular

I have this object:

```
elements120: {
    "data": {
        "name": "120",
        "type": "120"
    },
    "children": [
        {
            "data": {
                "name": "120A",
                "type": "120A"
            },
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "data": {
                "name": "120B",
                "type": "120B"
            },
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "data": {
                "name": "120C",
                "type": "120C"
            },
            "children": []
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to make some new Json as these below:

**Json 1:**

```
filtered120A{
    "data": {
        "name": "120",
        "type": "120"
    },
    "children": [
        {
            "data": {
                "name": "120A",
                "type": "120A"
            },
            "children": []
        }
    ]
}
```

**Json 2:**

```
filtered120B{
    "data": {
        "name": "120",
        "type": "120"
    },
    "children": [
        {
            "data": {
                "name": "120B",
                "type": "120B"
            },
            "children": []
        }
    ]
}
```

**Json 3:**

```
filtered120C{
    "data": {
        "name": "120",
        "type": "120"
    },
    "children": [
        {
            "data": {
                "name": "120C",
                "type": "120C"
            },
            "children": []
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried to do this in order to get only the first children node and delete the others (it's the only way it works me). For 120B and 120C i put as first child the value of the node that I needed for each case

```
this.filtered120A = utils.deepClone(this.elements120);
this.filtered120B = utils.deepClone(this.elements120);
this.filtered120C = utils.deepClone(this.elements120);

this.filtered120A = this.filtered120A.filter((element) => {
      delete element.children[1];
      delete element.children[2];
      return true;
    });

this.filtered120B = this.filtered120B.filter((element) => {
          element.children[0] = element.children[1];
          delete element.children[1];
          delete element.children[2];
          return true;
        });

this.filtered120C = this.filtered120C.filter((element) => {
          element.children[0] = element.children[2];
          delete element.children[1];
          delete element.children[2];
          return true;
        });
```

It works, but the code is not very elegant. I would like to know if there is any other better alternative.

Comment: Is this the full code? Where are the values of `this.filtered120A`, `this.filtered120B`, and `this.filtered120C` coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```js
function getOutputs(input) {
    const outputs = [];
    for (const child of input.children) {
        outputs.push({
            "data": {
                "name": input.data.name,
                "type": input.data.type
            },
            "children": [child]
        });
    }
    return outputs;
}

const inputs = {
    "data": {
        "name": "120",
        "type": "120"
    },
    "children": [
        {
            "data": {
                "name": "120A",
                "type": "120A"
            },
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "data": {
                "name": "120B",
                "type": "120B"
            },
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "data": {
                "name": "120C",
                "type": "120C"
            },
            "children": []
        }
    ]
};

const outputs = getOutputs(inputs);
console.log(outputs[0]); // output1
console.log(outputs[1]); // output2
console.log(outputs[2]); // output3
```